# Find all of the rows in that are in a subgroup of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am having a difficult time explaining this in words.
What I am trying to do:
I have the following table

```
employerID, userID
45          1
48          1
53          1
45          2
55          2
```

I want to build a query to return the rows

```
employerID, userID
45          1
48          1
53          1
45          2
and omit
55          2
```

the employer id of 55 is not in the rows that contain userID 1.

I want to find all rows where userID = 2 that its employerID is in the group of all of the rows where the userID = 1

I want to specify userid 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to find all rows where either the `userID = 1` or where at least one record exist with the same `employerID` and `userID = 1`?

Then you can use this sql which does exactly that:

```
SELECT employerID, userID
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE t.userID = 1  -- either userID = 1
OR                  -- or userID = 2 but with another record with userID = 1 and the same  employerID
(
    t.userID = 2 AND EXISTS            
    (
       SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableName t1
       WHERE t1.userID = 1
       AND   t1.employerID = t2.employerID
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but it seems like what you want to get:

```
Select * from tableA a
Where userID = 2
And not exists (
select 1 from tableA 
where employerID = a.employerID 
and userID = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple self inner join will do the trick:

```
SELECT a.employerID, a.userID
FROM tbl a INNER JOIN tbl b
ON(a.employerID = b.employerID)
WHERE (a.userID = 1 AND b.userID = 2)
OR (a.userID = 2 AND b.userID = 1)
```

Comment: But this omits all records with `userID=1` that don't have another record with `a.userID = 2`. If that's correct you haven't explained your requirement clearly enough.

Comment: ?? this query returns `45 1` and 
`45 2`.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri This is odd indeed, But according to the text that is what is needed. However this conflicts with the sample data output

Comment: I wrote my answer by the text... :-)

Comment: Actually, I found an error It doesn't pull all of the a.userID=1 rows, I want all of user = 1 rows and only the rows that user=2 and user = 1 has in common

Comment: well, I guess it wasn't so clear after all :-). in that case, Tim's answer is better indeed.

Answer (score 1):

One more version:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( EmpID INT, UserID INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 45, 1 ),
        ( 48, 1 ),
        ( 53, 1 ),
        ( 45, 2 ),
        ( 55, 2 )


SELECT  * FROM    @t
WHERE   EmpID NOT IN ( SELECT EmpID FROM @t WHERE UserID = 2
                       EXCEPT
                       SELECT EmpID FROM @t WHERE UserID = 1 )
```

Output:

```
EmpID   UserID
45      1
48      1
53      1
45      2
```